# Common scripting languages to be used for Jenkins + SVN + JIRA + Maven?

Tags: svn, scripting, jenkins, automation, jira

I come from an IBM Rational tools background where Perl is the de fact scripting language for the automation.

Now I am working on all these open source tools, and feel I need to pick up a more suitable scripting language for this set of tools. What's the best couple I have to pick up? Groovy? Jython?

Thanks
Jirong

Answer (score 0):

Most of those products have a REST API:

- [Jenkins REST API](https://builds.apache.org/api/)
- [JIRA REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/jira/6.1.html)
- [Maven REST API](https://maven.java.net/nexus-core-documentation-plugin/core/docs/index.html)

Even Subversion, in some commercial release, has a [REST API](https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.svnedge/wiki/ApiDocs). SVN itself has a [C/JavaHL API](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/).
But SVNKit provides a [full Java API](http://svnkit.com/download.php).

So any Java-compatible language can work here, both for programmatic calls with java API (generally available for those products), or for call over the web (REST API).

Comment: One more factor is deployment to the middlewares such as application servers and maybe even updating databases. What will be your best pick?

Comment: @user2784896 REST API remains a good choice, in that they provide webhook (https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+Webhooks+Overview): if you have a listener for those http callbacks, you can trigger your deployment based on the content sent by those hooks.